# Are the $\mathsf{HOD}$s preserved by weakly homogeneous forcings?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

We saw the following theorem in class:

> Let $M$ be a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, let $\Bbb P\in M$ be a weakly homogeneous partially ordered set, let $G$ be $\Bbb P$-generic over $M$ and let $A$ be a class in $M[G]$ with $A\subseteq M$. Then $\mathsf{HOD}_A^{M[G]}\subseteq M$.

By the question linked in the comments we have $\mathsf{HOD}_A^{M[G]}\subseteq\mathsf{HOD}_{A\cup\{\Bbb P\}}^M$, is there a simple example that shows that this inclusion can be strict? are there natural assumptions on $\Bbb P$ that guarantee an equality instead of an inclusion?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890051/why-does-mathsfhodvg-subseteq-mathsfhodv-hold-for-weakly-homogene

Comment: You need to have $\Bbb P$ as an element, not just its elements. So it should $A\cup\{\Bbb P\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I should improve my search skills... I updated the question accordingly to focus on the remaining doubts

Comment: I already left you a comment. :)

Comment: You're too fast! But that makes sense, to define the forcing relation in the ground model I need to be able to talk about $\Bbb P$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with $A=\varnothing$.

Start with $L$. Then there is a Suslin tree which is rigid there. Force with it to generate $V=L[A]$. By rigidity, the branch added is a unique branch in the tree, so it is ordinal definable (since the tree was in $L$). In particular, $V=\mathrm{HOD}$.

Now force with $\Bbb P=\operatorname{Col}(\omega,\omega_1)$. Then $V[G]=L[G]$, and so $\mathrm{HOD}^{V[G]}=L$, since $\Bbb P$ is in fact in $L$ and homogeneous there. Therefore we have that:

$$\mathrm{HOD}^{V[G]}=L\subsetneq V=\mathrm{HOD}^V=\mathrm{HOD}^V_{\{\Bbb P\}}.$$

Comment: For some reason I have doubts about this, so I'm only, say $\exp(\sqrt2\pi)\%$ behind it until someone comes to corroborate.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Suslin trees and I don't know what $\mathrm{Col}(\omega,\omega_1)$ stands for, so I can't really say whether I'm convinced by your argument!

Comment: Well. For Suslin trees, I recommend starting with Jech, Kunen, or any of the other basic books. For the collapse, that's essentially forcing with $\omega_1^{<\omega}$, i.e. finite functions from $\omega$ to $\omega_1$. This is known also as the Levy collapse and it is one of the most important forcings in set theory.

Comment: Oh, of course, I was just unfamiliar with the notation, it's the same as what we call $\mathrm{Fn}(\omega,\omega_1,\omega)$ in class, finite partial functions $\omega\to\omega_1$. (More generally $\mathrm{Fn}(\lambda,\mu,\kappa)$ are partial functions $\lambda\to\mu$ of cardinality less than $\kappa$ and for $\lambda\geq\kappa$ this adds a surjection $\lambda\to\mu$)

Comment: As flexible as that notation is... I hate it with a true passion of an opinionated jerk.